# PowerApps link to external webpage

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am new to PowerApps.  I have taken a spreadsheet that contains locations of our different billboards.   In the spreadsheet, I have the link to see the webcam.   However, in power apps it won't make that url as clickable.   If I put a button, I cannot get it to open a webpage at all?

I am unsure if I am missing something.   I have tried using function on click launch but it still isn't working right.   I guess the first question I would have is can I actually use a button or a link that can be clicked to open a page?  And if so, does it have to be a page in Sharepoint or can I use it to say open google.com?

Comment: Is the Launch function not working for you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-param

Can you post what formulas you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can launch an external site by setting the `OnSelect` property (say for a button) to :

```
Launch( "https://www.google.com/" )
```

You can also launch another canvas app:

```
Launch( "/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apps/ <YOUR APP ID>" )
```

Or launch the default email app with the To: address filled

```
Launch("mailto:123@gmail.com")
```

You can read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-param